# Error when deploying JSF application on Tomcat Server

Tags: jsf, tomcat, deployment

When I develop my JSF application in localhost, with glassfish Server, it works, but when I deploy it in my server (Tomcat 7.0) it shows following exception, can anybody resolve this issue?

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "#{initParam.pageWidth}" to class "javax.el.ValueExpression" for attribute "value": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager

        org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.getValueFromPropertyEditorManager(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:846)

        org.apache.jsp.details_jsp._jspx_meth_h_005foutputText_005f0(details_jsp.java:415)

        org.apache.jsp.details_jsp._jspService(details_jsp.java:159)

        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)

        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)

        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)

        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)

        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

        com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:546)

        com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)

        com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)

        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)

        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)

        com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)

        javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.6.1.RELEASE/7.0.20.B.RELEASE logs.
```

Comment: #{initParam.pageWidth}" would mean some lib is missing on Tomcat Runtime lib? http://weblogs.java.net/blog/cayhorstmann/archive/2009/12/29/jsf-20-and-tomcat

Comment: Please list the JARs you have in `/WEB-INF/lib`, including the versions.

Comment: jsf-api.jar 2.0
jsf-impl.jar 2.0
jstl.jar

Answer (score -1):

U have to check for main 3 libraries::jsf-api.jar,jsf-impl.jar,jstl.jarto solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 
I have added the three libraries, but still have that problem.

Comment: Look at the stack trace, both the JSF API/impl are present in there. Further, absence of JSTL would have caused a startup error, but OP is already beyond startup. So that is not the cause of OP's problem at all. In the future, please try to *explain* the solution as well. If you can't, then it's possibly not a valid solution at all.